# Tableau - How to set a parameter to a specific value if another parameter is selected

Tags: parameters, action, tableau-api

In Tableau, is there a way to change the value of a parameter when another parameter is changed?

For example, let say, I have 3 parameters on a sheet.

Parameter A has three choices A1 and A2 and None
Parameter B has three choices B1 and B2 and None
Parameter C has two choice C1 and None

and here is a scenario.

1. By default, all of the parameters are set to None.
2. Now, if a user changes parameter A from None to A2.
3. Then, if the user changes parameter B from None to B1 without changing the parameter A back to None manually.

Can we link the parameters in a way that if the user executes step number 3 then parameter A is changed back to None?

Comment: Do you mean that user may have choice either none from all parameters OR exactly one choice from either of three psrameters (other two set to none)?

Comment: one choice from one of three parameters and set other parameters to none.